# Is there any existing Javascript APIs manipulate canvas / images more advance?

Tags: html

Sorry if this sounds childish. I have been trying to manipulate a canvas element (of HTML5) (eg. a long rectangle) by folding the edge, like you are folding a paper.

Is there an existing javascript APIs for this? Or any recommendation where to begin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

A Javascript 3d engine

Comment: It was a nice approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of any specific framework or general purpose library for this sort of thing, but you might want to look at this: http://jpageflipper.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't really help much, but did guide me :3